# Rule-based labelling in QGIS not working

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule-based

[image]I have a map of the Isles of Scilly, I have geopackage data such as 'points of interest' that show me the island names and other places on the islands. I am trying to change the labels so that the island names are in bold and the other POI's are in a smaller font. I have followed my tutors video... using rule-based labelling, and creating the rule fontheight = 'large' for the islands. But when I click apply, all of the labels disappear.

How can I fix this?

[image: confusion]

Comment: Does your data have a "fontheight" attribute? Seems odd. The rule should be an expression that matches the attributes of the features, maybe something like `type='island` or `pop > 1000000` to select large cities. Can't tell without seeing your data...

Comment: I have added another photo, showing the attribute table. The data is all in order.... right?

Comment: @Spacedman double are for field/attributes, single quotes are for strings.

Comment: @Alrl aargh yes. it should be `fontheight='Large'` according to the attribute table and that is different to `fontheight='large'` (and very different to `fontheight="Large"` which would compare a field called "fontheight" with the value of a **field** called "Large"). There's a "test" button next to the rule in the rule settings dialog. If you click that, it should report the count of matching features. What do you get? Maybe your field has trailing spaces in it so its not exact matching?

Comment: I poked at this for an hour before arriving at this conclusion at lunch time today. Thanks for your help anyway! want to tutor me on linear regression and other statistical modelling stuff? (that's where I am struggling the most on my degree haha)